# Rails 4 equivalent to SQL "select count"?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got a query in SQL:

```
SELECT Foreign_id, Type, COUNT(Type) FROM events GROUP BY Type, Foreign_id
```

Foreign_id is, obviously, the foreign key (and primary key of another table), and Type is a descriptor of the event type.  This query, when run in the SQL client I am using on my MYSQL server, returns exactly what I am looking for.

I am wondering the most efficient way to run this in a Rails controller (there is a massive number of records).  Right now I have no idea how to turn this into a single command in Rails.  Here is what I have in my controller:

```
@foreign = Foreign.all
```

I then use this in the view:

```
<% foreign.each do |foreign| %>
  <%= foreign.events.select{|event| event.Type == 'A'}.size %><br />
  <%= foreign.events.select{|event| event.Type == 'B'}.size %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

I know there is a way more efficient way to get that number.  Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rails docs say to do this:](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-count)

```
Person.count
# => the total count of all people

Person.count(:age)
# => returns the total count of all people whose age is present in database

Person.count(:all)
# => performs a COUNT(*) (:all is an alias for '*')

Person.distinct.count(:age)
# => counts the number of different age values

Person.group(:city).count
# => { 'Rome' => 5, 'Paris' => 3 }

Article.group(:status, :category).count
# =>  {["draft", "business"]=>10, ["draft", "technology"]=>4, ["published", "business"]=>0, ["published", "technology"]=>2}

Person.select(:age).count
# => counts the number of different age values
```

So in your case I believe you'd do it like so:

```
@foreign = Foreign.events.select('Type','A').count()
```

Comment: This is very close to exactly what I am looking for, thank you so much.  In the example with Article.group(:status, :category).count, what if I only wanted published articles, but still grouped by status and category?

Comment: Then you'd add a scope to your Article model and do this: `Article.published.group(:status, :category).count`. [See this article in the Rails docs about scopes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html)

Answer (score 0):

If there are only 2 `types`, this would be appropriate:

```
<% @foreigns.each do |foreign| %>
  <%= foreign.events.where( type: 'A' ).count %><br />
  <%= foreign.events.where( type: 'B' ).count %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Wow queries in your view..
MVC? hmm